# python o/p not printing in defined file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the code I am using to do some statistical work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fn = 'ip.txt'
F,error = np.loadtxt(fn,unpack=True, usecols=[0,1]) 

for i in range(len(F)):

 xbar = np.mean(F)
Ssquare = (F-xbar)*(F-xbar)
S1= np.sum(Ssquare)
S= S1/(len(F)-1)
for i in range(len(error)):
 ms = np.sum(error)/len(error)
 sigma = np.sum((error*error))
 ss = sigma/len(error)
 Fvs = (S)/(xbar*xbar)
 Fva = np.sqrt(Fvs)
 rms  = np.sqrt(ss)

f=open('out.txt','w') 
f.write('xbar\t\t ms\t\t rms\t\t Fva\n')
print (xbar, ms, rms, Fva)
f.close()
```

The code runs fine but the output is the following

```
$ python F.py

xbar meansigma rmssigma Fvariance <_io.TextIOWrapper name='out.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

If I try giving print like this,

```
print (xbar, ms, rms, Fva)
```

it prints in the terminal. I want it to print in the file that I have defined.

Comment: You already used `write` to write to the file. How did you get the idea that you should use `print`?

Comment: Nothing to do with matplotlib. Tag removed

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the print statements, remove the file writing code, and just use unix functions

```
python F.py > F.txt
```

Otherwise, you need to use `f.write` again, not print, if you want to continue to write data to your file

Comment: I need to write the data to the file and also see it. As of now only these headings (**xbar ms rms Fva**) are in the output file not the values for these headings.

Comment: Yes... Because your code only has one line that does `f.write`. Have you tried doing it again? If so, what output do you get, then? Could you update the question with that code and file output?

Answer (score 0):

if you want write a something in text file then it will be helpful to you

```
file1 = open("myfile.txt","w") 
L = ["This is Delhi \n","This is Paris \n","This is London \n"]  

# \n is placed to indicate EOL (End of Line) 
file1.write("Hello \n") 
file1.writelines(L) 
file1.close() #to change file access modes
```